# Do I really need Ingress?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an application with a microservice environment and I am deploying that with terraform to my Kubernetes cluster.

Because of internal reasons we have written our own API Gateway, which I now added as a deployment and a service in Kubernetes up and running.

Now my question is: Do I need an ingress?

As far as I can see and read about it, it is useful as a single point of entry for my cluster, which is fine, but that is exactly what my API Gateway does. So couldn't I just expose my ApiGateway as entrypoint as a LoadBalancer-Type in my Service declaration of my Kubernetes deployment file?

Do it has pros/cons when I do this or is this bad practice?

Comment: A request to discuss the pros/cons of some library/technology stack isn't really a question in the scope of this community. Different people have different opinions on such topics, and the "right" decision always depends on many factors, such as your environment, and often important: the skill level in the teams running the overall solution for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should Kubernetes Ingress lives together with a Spring Cloud Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189841/should-kubernetes-ingress-lives-together-with-a-spring-cloud-gateway)